# PHPJS' array_diff returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, phpjs

**Example:**

> http://jsfiddle.net/7Cwbn/60/

I'm trying to use `array_diff` function from **PHPJS** to check if all of the elements inside `selectedFeatures` are found inside `elem.features`, but instead I receive `undefined`. What gives?

```
$(markers.houses).each(function(index, elem) {
        //first filter by selected features
        console.log(array_diff(elem.features, selectedFeatures).length);
        if (array_diff(selectedFeatures, elem.features).length == 0) {
            if (!markers.houseMarkers[index].visible) {
                markers.houseMarkers[index].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Inside `array_diff()` definition change the `retVal` to equal `[]` instead of `{}`.